# What can I call the different type of groups in this scenario?

Tags: word-request

Local volunteers can join certain groups to contribute their services, and the rules are:

> 1. a volunteer must choose one group as the `initial group`, and he serves in this group  most of the time
> 2. a volunteer can join multiple `non-initial groups` according to their interests, but he only serves in those groups in spare time

Now I'd like to find two words to identify the `initial group` & `non-initial group`.

How can I express this?

(here's some examples that I don't know if ok)

> 1. Primary Group & Secondary Group
> 2. Major Group & Minor Group
> 3. ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of ways you can name the groups.

1 would be correct, as the groups are primary and secondary to a certain volunteer, but I don't think 2 is a good option: major and minor suggest size instead of priority, and the fact that the volunteer doesn't consider the second group as his/her main group doesn't make it smaller.

It's important to consider that the names you choose are in relation to the volunteer, rather to the groups themselves.

Some other examples I can think of are:

> 1. Main group and secondary groups
> 2. Main group and additional groups
> 3. Main group and minor groups

Any of those replacing *Main* with *Head* or *Primary* would also be correct.